# Difference between 'Is came/has came/ came'

Tags: sentence-construction

What is the difference in meaning if we use "is" in the sentence below?

a) What is came first egg or chicken?
b) what came first egg or chicken?
c) what has came first egg or chicken?

Comment: A cock doesn't lay eggs (I may have to get a t-shirt made up with that on it)

Comment: The original phrase is "Which came first, the chicken or the egg?"

Comment: Makes it a whole new joke, phrased that way ;)

Comment: Grammatically your first sentence is incorrect .

Comment: cock or egg?!! which came first?  what a hilarious joke! I think it is cock!

Comment: The base forms of to come are come/came/come.
A combination of "is+came (past tense)" does not occur in English.
After have/has/had you need the base form 3.

Answer (score 1):

The difference isn't in meaning. Adding the verb to be, i.e. "is" in your example makes the sentence ungrammatical.

The proper verb to use here is come in the past simple, which corresponds to your example b.

The sentence should read:

> Which came first: the egg or the chicken?

(Which instead of what - because you have two options to chose from; the definite article - because the metaphor refers to the very first egg and very first chicken).

The first sentence uses the auxiliary *be* in combination with the past simple form 'came' - this is simply ungrammatical, I can't think of any construction in English, which would combine these two.

The last example (c) combines auxiliary *have* with past simple form 'came', which is also ungrammatical. If you combined *have* with the past partciple 'come' you would get present perfect:

> Which has come first: the egg or the chicken?

But, while technically grammatical, this sentence is in the wrong tense - past simple fits better here.