# Using "is" and "are" with Verb

Tags: sentence-construction, tense, sentence-meaning

Please help me to understand when and how to use *is and are* with a verb?

> 1. Your letter is not yet come/came.
> 2. Tree is fallen on him.
> 3. Train is arrived.
> 4. current is Gone
> 5. He is died due to cancer.

Also, if I use *has* instead of *is* does it change the meaning?

Answer (score 3):

As ultrasawblade said:

- be (auxiliary) + past participle (of the main verb) = passive voice.

> *In the passive, the person or thing that the action was done to becomes the topic or theme.* ([CDO English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/passive?q=Passive))

This means that there has to be something/someone to whom the action was done, i.e. the verb should be transitive.

*Come, fall, arrive and die* are intransitive verbs, so your examples 1, 2, 3 and 5 are ungrammatical.

Your 4th sentence is different, because the verb to be is used as a copula (not an auxiliary to form the passive) so the meaning of the sentence is that the current is no longer present (it could make sense if you were talking of electric current).

On the other hand:

- have (auxiliary) + past participle (of the main verb) = [present perfect](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/present-perfect-simple-i-have-worked)

With *have* as an auxiliary all your sentences would be grammatical, although 4 might sound a bit strange.

---

See [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/60160/difference-between-is-came-has-came-came/60169#60169) for an explanation why *is + came* is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 2):

Almost every English verb can be used as an actual, real verb or take the form of a present or past participle.  The present or past participle can be used as a modifier, or as an *auxillary* or *helping* verb.

English has various verb tenses and moods, and some tenses are expressed with one word, and others with more than one word - which is a form of *to be* + present or past participle, or a form of *to have* + past participle.  It's best to think of the entire phrase (*to be* or *to have* + auxillary/helping verb) as the verb.

Progressive tenses use *to be* + present participle.

Passive moods use *to be* + past participle.

Perfect tenses use *to have* + past participle.

Each of these has a different meaning.

There are also *modal auxillaries* such as *will*, *would*, etc. that express future and conditional tenses.

Long story short: [study your tenses](http://www.pearltrees.com/s/pic/or/english-tenses-46765437)!